# Declaring StringStream in QT Problem

Tags: c++, qt, stringstream

I am having problem in declaring StringStream in QT. 
Here is my code:

```
 std::stringstream ss;
                 for (int i = 0; i <= path.length()-1; ++i)
                 {
                    if (path[i] == '\\')
                    {
                        ss << "\\\\";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    ss << path[i];
                    }
                 }
                    path = QString::fromStdString(ss.str());//store the stringstream to a string
         return path;
```

the error message is:

```
aggregate 'std::stringstream ss' has incomplete type and cannot be defined;
```

Comment: What line is causing the error, and what error message are you getting?

Comment: Umm..what is the problem? its not compiling? Please post the error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mixing `QString` and `std::string` or related is not generally a good idea. You should implement that with `QString` methods like [`replace( QChar ch, const QString & after, Qt::CaseSensitivity cs = Qt::CaseSensitive)`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qstring.html#replace-10).

```
path.replace('\\', "\\\\");
```

BTW, you can't use QString directly with any of the standard `std` streams, there are no overloads defined. The `qPrintable` function can help though. And you need to include `<sstream>` to use `std::stringstream`.

Comment: this code works, I just tested it. make sure you have the right `'` and `"` quotes and the right number of slashes. and give the exact compiler error of it doesn't.

Comment: -1, wrong on the most important part. You need `<sstream>`. Some implementations may include `<sstream>` in `<iostream>`, which explains why it worked on one compiler.

Answer (score 2):

Include `<sstream>` to use the `stringstream` class.

Though I do agree with @Mat that it would probably be a good idea to use Qt's QString methods for this particular purpose.